# Calendar API How to get month from getTime(); saved as a variable

Tags: java

Using the Calendar API I want to store the date of object creation in its instance field. The object is then saved to a text file.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date todaysDate = cal.getTime();
Object obj = new Object(todaysDate);
```

Later, I want to return the month the object was created. However, the date was stored as type 'Date'and AFAIK the Date API doesn't have a method to return the month.

Is there a way to store the date in a variable that allows me to use Calendar methods?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date)

Comment: Check this out? http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this my friend

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date todaysDate = cal.getTime();
            int month = todaysDate.getMonth()+1;
            System.out.println(month);

    }
```

Comment: @user3261486 have you tried this

Comment: This uses a Date method. The method is deprecated. However, it works just fine. I'll have to read up on deprecation.

Comment: @user3261486 deprecation means that it is old but java's current version  still supports it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Get `Calendar` from `Date`. Month number is started from 0

```
// current date
Date todaysDate = calendar.getTime();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

// Init `Calendar` from `Date`
calendar.setTime(todaysDate);

// Get month nimber from `Calendar` object 
final int monthNumber = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```